# Shopware - how to save something to custom fields

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6

I am creating an application (not plugin) to integrate with shipping companies. However, I can't deal with one problem - custom fields. I created one and linked it to an order. How can I save something to this field? It is called custom_parcel_locker_field. The template in which I need to display this field is:
`storefront/component/shipping/shipping-method.html.twig`

Tried to insert something like this, but didn't work:

```
<input type="text" name="customFields['custom_parcel_locker_field']">
```

```
<input type="text" name="custom_parcel_locker_field">
```

I need the customer to be able to write something to this field.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to save the custom field on the checkout page when a customer makes an order.

Extend the template `shipping-method.html.twig` by creating a new template file `src/Resources/views/storefront/component/shipping/shipping-method.html.twig`:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/component/shipping/shipping-method.html.twig' %}

{% block extended_block_name %}
   {{ parent() }}

   <input type="text" name="customParcelLockerField" form="confirmOrderForm">
{% endblock %}
```

Shopware won't save this field automatically. You have to do this on your own using a subscriber. A good place to do this is for example the `CartConvertedEvent`. It is dispatched when customer's cart is converted to an order.

Create a new file `src/Subscriber/CartConvertedSubscriber.php` containing your subscriber class:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace YourNamespace\Subscriber;

use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Order\CartConvertedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class CartConvertedSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private RequestStack $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            CartConvertedEvent::class => 'addCustomFieldsToOrder'
        ];
    }

    public function addCustomFieldsToOrder(CartConvertedEvent $event): void
    {
        $orderData = $event->getConvertedCart();
        $orderCustomFields = $orderData['customFields'] ?? [];

        $customParcelLocker = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->request->get('customParcelLockerField');

        if ($customParcelLocker) {
            $orderCustomFields['custom_parcel_locker_field'] = $customParcelLocker;
        }

        $orderData['customFields'] = $orderCustomFields;

        $event->setConvertedCart($orderData);
    }
}
```

Then register your subscriber in `src/Resources/config/services.xml`:

```xml
<service id="YourNamespace\Subscriber\CartConvertedSubscriber">
   <argument type="service" id="request_stack"/>
   <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

Comment: Can I do something like this in applications? This solution seems to work for the plugin, but the application does not have services and eventsubscribers, it communicates through webhooks

Comment: @PiotrSzostakiewicz sorry, I missed that you are working on an app, not a plugin. I don't think it will be possible with an app.